# Java : Socket connections with simple Blacklist

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

So i'm making a simple client-server application in Java. As simple as it gets, i think, and i'm trying to implement a blacklist.txt that has several IP Addresses that will be refused to connect if any of the IP's there match the IP trying to connect to the Socket. I'm kind of new at this, but here's what I got:

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(6500);
    System.out.println ("Server Started on port 6500");     
    while (true){//Waiting clients
        Socket socket = null;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\UNIV\\Redes\\workspace\\Copy of Ex_4.3_Teste\\lists\\blacklist.txt"));
        String line = null;
        socket = server.accept();

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line == socket.getInetAddress().toString()) {
                 System.out.println("IP Blacklisted: " + socket.getInetAddress().toString());
                 socket.close(); //Refusing connection
            }
            System.out.println("Line: " + line); //Just checking if reading OK
            System.out.println("Socket: " + socket.getInetAddress().toString()); //Just checking if reading OK

        }

        System.out.println("New connection..");

        Thread t = new Thread(new EchoClientThread(socket));                             
        t.start();          
    }       
}
```

Then I start a thread for each connecting client, but I think that's not relevant to what i'm asking.

The whole idea is to refuse connecting if the IP Address is equal to any line of the blacklist.txt

I clearly have something wrong here, because it's not working, can someone point me in the right direction please ?

Much appreciated.

EDIT: Forgot the contents of blacklist.txt:

```
/192.168.2.200
/127.0.0.1
```

I put the slashes before the IPs because I noticed the output from `socket.getInetAddress().toString()` was `/IP.IP.IP.IP`

Comment: Java strings should be compared via `.equals()`

Comment: @dlev Yea, you are totally right, my mistake. It works now, and i'm totally ashamed ^^ If you want, add that as a solution, and i'll accept it.

Comment: Glad things work now. Honestly, I think the better resolution would be to delete the question, since it is fairly localized.

Comment: I would recommend you extend serverSocket and create a class like BlacklistingServerSocket with the accept method overloaded. Makes more elegant code instead of mixing all the logic together in one place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line

```
if (line == socket.getInetAddress().toString()) {
```

to

```
if (line.equals(socket.getInetAddress().toString())) {
```

Strings are objects (not primitive types like `int`, `float`, `char`) and should be compared with `.equals()`.